# In Minkowski space, why does the hyperboloid appear to each observer as a circle whose radius is increasing faster than the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry

I read the assumption in the above question in the paper *Hyperbolic geometry on a Hyperboloid* by William F. Reynolds (see [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324297), page 444), but it was not clarified further (the discussion was rather short). I don't have a good understanding of special relativity but I suspect it has something to do with the (positive sheet of the) hyperboloid being bound asymptotically by the "future light coin" of Minkowski space.

I would like to understand the connection between the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry and special relativity better. The connection is through Minkowski spacetime. I asked about this connection on math.SE, for anyone who would also like to understand it better I recommend this [this great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497504/what-is-the-relationship-between-hyperbolic-geometry-and-einsteins-special-rela/666294#666294) to my question.

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect it to be any different?

Comment: @DavidZ Because "faster than light" sounds strange to me. (Note: I am not well-educated in physics).

Comment: Yes, but you've traced out an arbitrary path in spacetime, and you're asserting that it seems strange for it to be faster than light. Why? What makes you think this arbitrary path should be slower than light in the first place?

Comment: Because of my (possibly stupid) notion that "nothing can be faster than light" so if one were to travel along this path, one would violate that rule.

Comment: OK, but are you saying that something is traveling along this path? I don't see that in the question. Perhaps you could clarify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the diagram you've drawn, any line with a gradient of greater than one is timelike and any line with a gradient of less than one is spacelike. As your diagram shows, the gradient of all radial lines (i.e. outwards from the time axis) on the hyperboloid have a gradient of less than one. So to the observer whose light cone it is, any object following one of those lines would be travelling faster than light. Since the points on your expanding circles follow these trajectories the circles must be expanding faster than light.

Answer (score 2):

This hyperboloid is not a physical object; therefore there's no restriction against it moving faster than light.

It is "spacelike". One way to define it is to have a bunch of test particles explode out of the origin at t=0, each of them carrying a clock. Have each test particle wait some constant amount of proper time T. Because of time dilation, this will correspond to a later value of t for the particles nearer the light cone. After proper time T, the positions of the particles will trace out this hyperboloid.

At each particle, the hyperboloid will be tangent to that particle's local notion of space. In a sense, seen from "inside," the world of the test particles is an expanding universe with negatively curved hyperbolic geometry, even though we started with a completely flat spacetime. Since the hyperboloid is a *spacelike* slice of the world, we shouldn't expect any aspect of it to be traveling slower than light.

(This construction is actually the basis of an obsolete cosmological model, the Milne "kinematic relativity" model. You can also think of it as the zero-mass limit of the Friedman-Robertson-Walker cosmology with no cosmological constant.)